# subvariety of $(\mathbb P^1)^4$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be the sub-algebra generated by the set $S=\{ x_1x_2y_3y_4,\  x_1x_3y_2y_4,\  x_1x_4y_2y_3,\ x_2x_3y_1y_4,\ x_2x_4y_1y_3,\ x_3x_4y_1y_2 \}$ of homogeneous polynomials. I need to compute $Proj(S)$.

The relation among the above set of polynomials are $f_1f_6=f_2f_5=f_3f_4$ in the above order. So the projective dimension is $3$. Looks like this is a $3$ dimensional sub-variety of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ but what is this variety ?